# How to get DOM ELEMENT DATA in Aura Component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I am trying to get element in Aura. Actually I have made a functionality in VF and now I want to move the same functionality to Aura.

In VF I use `document.getElementsByClassName('chart');` which give me this
**`[object HTMLCollection]`** as a result.

for achieving the same functionality in Aura I use `component.find("chart").getElement();` which give me **`isSecureElement: [object HTMLCanvasElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }`**

My Question is how to extract **`[object HTMLCanvasElement]`** from above result as I need to pass this element to a third party library.

Can anyone suggest me any idea

Comment: Lightning Aura implements [secure wrappers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_global_access.htm) and you cannot modify the DOM directly due to this secure wrapper restriction. What do you want to actually pass to the external library?

Comment: @Moonpie, I am passing HTML canvas to domtoimage library